# Ceiling fan starting problems

Tags: ceiling-fan

Fan on start up it goes in one direction then the other then goes in the direction slowly then stops I have check all the wiring connections.  Any body have these problems? I need help fan is a DC fan maker is Bojue

Comment: Can you attach a picture of how you connected the wires?  Make sure it's in good focus with suitable light to clearly see the colors of the wires.